# Divergence of an infinite product

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

How can I prove that the infinite product

$$\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}(1+z^{2n})$$

diverges for 
$|z|>1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|1+z^{2n}|\geqslant |z|^{2n}-1\to +\infty$, so the partial products cannot converge.

Answer (score 3):

Irrelevant to your question but, its to big to put in a comment,

I thought I should mention the nice identity
$$\prod_{k=0}^\infty(1+x^{2^k})=\frac{1}{1-x}\text{ , for all  x < 1}$$

Comment: yes, i just proved this identity, but then i was asked to prove the divergence and since it looked too obvious i thought i was missing something, so i asked

Comment: @Ethan: As far as I know, you are not allowed to publicly ask about errors. Of course, if you were to post the question anonymously...

Comment: @ZevChonoles I just deleted the question, did your comment somehow get re-directed here, or was that on purpose?

Comment: @Ethan: On purpose.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Quite off topic, but did you go to Chicago as an undergraduate? If so, I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me some advice on answering https://collegeadmissions.uchicago.edu/apply/essays/.

Comment: @Ethan: No, I went to Brown University for undergrad. [See my post here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/82979/264). Brown and UChicago are both excellent schools, but they are extremely different academically. UChicago is intense and regimented, Brown is almost absurdly laid back.

Comment: @Ethan: Also, the common wisdom is to avoid going to the same place for graduate study that one went to as an undergraduate. [See this Academia.SE thread](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/224/222).

Comment: @ZevChonoles Yeah I've heard that a lot, just thought it was worth asking.